# why istream,ostream,iostream,ios_base all work here

Tags: c++, state, bit

```
int main()
{
int a=0;
int b=0;
std::cout<<"Please enter an int: "<<std::endl;
std::cin>>a;
auto old_state =std::cin.rdstate(); // remember the current state of cin
std::cin.clear(); // make cin valid
std::cout<<"Please enter another int: "<<std::endl;
std::cin>>b;// use cin
auto new_state = std::cin.rdstate();
if(old_state==std::istream::failbit&&new_state==std::istream::failbit) 
//I tried std::ostream,std::iostream,ios_base they all work.
std::cout<<"Both are failbit!"<<std::endl;
}
```

I just came across IO chapter on C++ Primer. I tried this code myself, and suprisingly found out that for the last two lines, I changed `std::istream` to `std::ostream`, `std::iostream`, `std::ios_base`, they all seems work when I typed in two `char`. Someone please help to explain this in plain words why could this happen. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh ok I got what you mean. cin is tied to cout so no need endl to clear buffer. Thanks for pointing this out!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `failbit` is a `public` member of `ios_base` and all the other classes `public`ly inherit from `ios_base`.